# Compare data frame and a list and divide data if exists or not exists in df in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have a data frame and a list of 50 elements that I need to compare and create another list with existing and not existing data in the df:

| POS | WORD | TRANSLATION | LEMMA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PRON | мин | I |  |
| PRON | кини | he, she |  |
| PRON | олор | it inanimate |  |
| PART | суох | no |  |
| ADV | манна | here |  |
| CCONJ | уонна | and |  |

```
List: 
[[1]]
[1] "мин"

[[2]]
[1] "биирдэ"

[[3]]
[1] "манна"

[[4]]
[1] "сааспар"

[[5]]
[1] "уонна"
```

If the word from the list IS IN the DF, then return POS, WORD, LEMMA
If NOT in the DF, then return "- WORD -"

This is what I have so far:

```
test <- list()
for (w in 1:length(pron$WORD)) {
  for (i in 1:length(sakha_text_50)) {
    if(sakha_text_50[i] == pron$WORD[w])
      print(test[[length(test) + 1]] <- paste(pron$POS[w], ":", pron$WORD[w], ":", pron$LEMMA[w]))
  }
}
```

However, when I write something like this, it prints everything, even what is in the list.
What could be a problem?

```
test <- list()
for (w in 1:length(pron$WORD)) {
  for (i in 1:length(sakha_text_50)) {
    if(sakha_text_50[i] == pron$WORD[w])
      print(test[[length(test) + 1]] <- paste(pron$POS[w], ":", pron$WORD[w], ":", pron$LEMMA[w]))
    if(sakha_text_50[i] != pron$WORD[w]) {
      print(test[[length(test) + 1]] <- paste("-", ":", sakha_text_50[i], ":", "-"))}
  }
}
```

The output should be something like:

```
"PRON : мин : "
"- : биирдэ: -"
"ADV: манна: "
"- : сааспар: -"
```

Comment: Please provide your data.frame and the word list as `dput()`. Edit your question and put those `structure()` output there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did so.

1. Preparation of the data frame and list
   (in the future, please post the code that generates the data)

```
library(tidyverse)  
df = tribble(
   ~POS,     ~WORD,    ~TRANSLATION, ~LEMMA,
   "PRON",   "мин",            "I",      NA,
   "PRON",  "кини",      "he, she",      NA,
   "PRON",  "олор", "it inanimate",      NA,
   "PART",  "суох",           "no",      NA,
    "ADV", "манна",         "here",      NA,
  "CCONJ", "уонна",          "and",      NA,
)

lst = list(
  "мин",
  "биирдэ",
  "манна",
  "сааспар",
  "уонна"
)
```

2. Converting the list into a data frame

```
dfl = tibble(
  l = map_chr(lst, function(l) l[[1]])
)
```

3. The comparison function

```
fcomp = function(x, dfl){
  x %in% dfl$l
}
```

4. Data comparison

```
df %>% mutate(
  output = ifelse(fcomp(WORD, dfl), 
                  paste(POS, ":", WORD, ":", LEMMA), 
                  paste("-",WORD, "-"))
) %>% pull(output)
```

Here is the result

```
[1] "PRON : мин : NA"    "- кини -"           "- олор -"           "- суох -"           "ADV : манна : NA"  
[6] "CCONJ : уонна : NA"
```

All without a single `for` command!

You can even more simple

```
fcomp = function(x, lst){
  x %in% map_chr(lst, function(l) l[[1]])
}
df %>% mutate(
  output = ifelse(fcomp(WORD, lst), 
                  paste(POS, ":", WORD, ":", LEMMA), 
                  paste("-",WORD, "-"))
) %>% pull(output)
```

Output:

```
[1] "PRON : мин : NA"   
[2] "- кини -"          
[3] "- олор -"          
[4] "- суох -"          
[5] "ADV : манна : NA"  
[6] "CCONJ : уонна : NA"
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! But what was the problem with for-loop? I'd like to know

Comment: `for` loops are used very rarely in R. I haven't analyzed your program. I just did it, you might say in "R style". Doesn't such a code seem clearer and more elegant to you?

Comment: It does, indeed. R is relatively new to me, practice make perfect!
There's an issue with my data though. The data frame that I have consists of 500.000 rows and the test list set is only 50 rows. Isn't mutate binds them all? The only thing I need to check is if these 50 words are in the df

Comment: @Witness1123 [This](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/04/functional-programming-in-r/) is a blog post you might find interesting.

Comment: Please see my second answer

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(microbenchmark)

df = tribble(
   ~POS,     ~WORD,    ~TRANSLATION, ~LEMMA,
   "PRON",   "мин",            "I",      NA,
   "PRON",  "кини",      "he, she",      NA,
   "PRON",  "олор", "it inanimate",      NA,
   "PART",  "суох",           "no",      NA,
    "ADV", "манна",         "here",      NA,
  "CCONJ", "уонна",          "and",      NA,
)

lst = list(
  "мин",
  "биирдэ",
  "манна",
  "сааспар",
  "уонна"
)

n = 1000000
df2 = tibble(
  LEMMA = NA,
  POS = rep(df$POS, n/6),
  WORD = rep(df$WORD, n/6),
  TRANSLATION = rep(df$TRANSLATION, n/6)
)


fcomp = function(x, lst){
  x %in% map_chr(lst, function(l) l[[1]])
}

f1 = function(df) df %>% 
  mutate(
    output = ifelse(fcomp(WORD, lst), paste(POS, ":", WORD, ":", LEMMA), paste("-",WORD, "-"))
  ) %>% pull(output)

microbenchmark(f1(df), f1(df2), times=20)
```

Output

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
  f1(df)    3.029024    3.297799    3.487867    3.522742    3.619176    4.100279    20
 f1(df2) 1167.555888 1180.183231 1203.688027 1185.045575 1212.139355 1356.857617    20
```

In a data frame containing 1,000,000 observations, this mutation takes an average of 1.2 seconds. Can you wait that long?